# How does HttpClient execute handle over-specified paths?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I noticed that the [`org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0-beta2/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.java#AbstractHttpClient.execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest%2Corg.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext%29) specifies an `execute` method that takes a target host and a request param.

```
/**
 * Executes a request to the target using the default context.
 *
 * @param target    the target host for the request.
 *                  Implementations may accept <code>null</code>
 *                  if they can still determine a route, for example
 *                  to a default target or by inspecting the request.
 * @param request   the request to execute
 *
 * @return  the response to the request. This is always a final response,
 *          never an intermediate response with an 1xx status code.
 *          Whether redirects or authentication challenges will be returned
 *          or handled automatically depends on the implementation and
 *          configuration of this client.
 * @throws IOException in case of a problem or the connection was aborted
 * @throws ClientProtocolException in case of an http protocol error
 */
HttpResponse execute(HttpHost target, HttpRequest request)
    throws IOException, ClientProtocolException;
```

I've delved into the `DefaultHttpClient` and `DefaultRequestDirector` source code, and it became apparent that the simpler `execute(HttpRequest request)` method separates the request into an HttpHost object and an HttpRequest object and forwards the call to the more specified method (actually, the one that also accepts an `HttpContext` object as well - but I don't care about the context at the moment).

My question is, since the request and the host can both accept a URI, how is the final URI determined? What is they both have an absolute URI included? What if they conflict? What is they both have partial paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpHost` represents a *physical* endpoint. It only contains authority part (scheme, host and port) of a `URI`. It does not contain a path. Request `URI` represents a resource that potentially can be *virtual*. There can be no conflicts. Only if `HttpHost` is not explicitly given the authority part of the request `URI` is assumed to be the physical endpoint

For instance

```
HttpHost = http://www.google.com:-1
Request URI = http://www.google.ch/stuff
```

Will result in the following message composition

TCP

```
localhost:<random> -> www.google.com:80
```

HTTP

```
GET /stuff HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.ch
```

You can see this behavior in the [`AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0-beta2/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.java#AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest%29) private helper method, which despite changing radically between 4.0 and 4.3.5 extracts just the scheme, host and port from the URI for variants of `execute` which don't supply an `HttpHost`. The code for where the target and request are composed back into the final route is more convoluted, but a careful reading of HttpRoute, HttpRoutePlanner, and HttpRequest impl methods all clearly refer to the `host` or `hostTarget` coming from the HTTP host and the path (and params and fragment) coming from the local part, which comes from the HttpRequest.

Comment: Thanks oleg. I had hoped that was the case, and with a little more digging through the related `Http...` classes mentioned in the edit, I'm fairly confident that your description is always the case... at least for the DefaultHttpClient class.